# Testing a Single Page Application while simulating the backend

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, websocket, single-page-application

I have a single page application developed using javascript, react and redux that communicates with the backend via web socket, rest and json.

I wish to explore the possibility of working independently of the backend, both as I develop and in terms of treating the front end as a subsystem and performing subsystem tests on it.

Is this a good approach? What tools would you recommend? For example, I have used selenium previously with python. Would it be a sensible option for me to write my own simple test environment using a selenium api where tests are configured in their setup to respond to rest requests from the front end in the appropriate manner. Maybe there are better approaches.

Comment: Do you want a test server to tun app on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I think npm provide [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

You can run server in your project dir and it should be server on localhost.

But if you are using Linux or Mac, the easiest way will be:

```
$ cd you_app_folder
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

As python is built in on mac and Linux it is easiest way as I said.